# Json DeserializeObject throws exception only by iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I don't have this problem by Android, but when I run the same working code in iOS then I get exception

```
public async Task Login(string inlogData, string password, string gcm) 
    {
        Login login = new Dharma.Login ();
        login.inlog_data = inlogData;
        login.password = password;
        login.phone_token = gcm;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login, Formatting.Indented);
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds (10000);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri (ConstantVariabels.GetLoginUrl());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new StringContent (json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        try 
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync (client.BaseAddress, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode ();
            var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result;

            dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonResult);
            string token = dynJson ["api_token"];   //THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION
            LoginPageViewModel.LoginSucceeded(token, true);
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException te) 
        {
            LoginPageViewModel.LoginSucceeded(te.Message.ToString(), false);
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException hre) 
        {
            LoginPageViewModel.LoginSucceeded(hre.Message.ToString(), false);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LoginPageViewModel.LoginSucceeded("fail", false);
        }
    }
```

## Exception

Message: Interpreter of ref types

StackTrace:

```
 at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileMethodCallExpression (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x00089] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1283 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileNoLabelPush (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x001ba] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1642 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.Compile (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1729 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileConditionalExpression (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, Boolean asVoid) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:818 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileNoLabelPush (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x001d2] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1644 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.Compile (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1729 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.Compile (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, Boolean asVoid) [0x00012] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1593 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileBlockExpression (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, Boolean asVoid) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:379 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileNoLabelPush (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x003d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1683 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.Compile (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1729 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileGotoExpression (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x0001f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:955 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileNoLabelPush (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x0042d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1689 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileAsVoid (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x00085] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1620 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.Compile (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, Boolean asVoid) [0x00006] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1591 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileConditionalExpression (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, Boolean asVoid) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:828 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileNoLabelPush (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x001d2] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1644 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileAsVoid (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x00085] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1620 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileBlockStart (System.Linq.Expressions.BlockExpression node) [0x000b0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:405 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileBlockExpression (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr, Boolean asVoid) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:376 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileNoLabelPush (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x003d0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1683 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.Compile (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:1729 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler.CompileTop (System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression node) [0x00055] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Interpreter/LightCompiler.cs:221 
  at Microsoft.Scripting.Generation.CompilerHelpers.LightCompile (System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression lambda) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Dynamic/Generation/CompilerHelpers.cs:619 
  at System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.LambdaCompiler.Compile (System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression lambda, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq.Expressions.Interpret/LambdaCompiler.cs:41 
  at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[TDelegate].Compile () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Scripting.Core/Ast/LambdaExpression.cs:188 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite`1 site, System.Object[] args) [0x00059] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Scripting.Core/Actions/CallSiteBinder.cs:148 
  at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet] (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSite site, System.Dynamic.T0 arg0) [0x0010d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3234/d8bedd03/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/dlr/Runtime/Microsoft.Scripting.Core/Actions/UpdateDelegates.Generated.cs:255 
  at Dharma.HttpRequests+<Login>c__async4.MoveNext () [0x0019e] in /Users/laurenspouders/dharmapp/Dharma/Library/HttpRequests.cs:345
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and found that the previous Newtonsoft JSON used to reference the "value" by default, but doesn't now, so just add a .Value

```
string token = dynJson ["api_token"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `dynJson ["api_token"]` returns the type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JTokenType.String` and you are assigning it to `string`. So the implicit conversion does not happen and gives an exception. Add an explicit cast it will work.

```
string token = (string)dynJson ["api_token"];
```

You must get the some error in Android too about the implicit cast.

Comment: what do you get in `dynJson` ?

Comment: dynJson {{   "api_token": "7Z4eV9DkaScrXkzGoWlgDHe26HyXATXKx2NBIBqHxbMtZ3kDmfU2O3FB9hk4" }} Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject

Comment: I don't find any problem in my code the only error I was getting was about the implicit conversion and the ans above solved my error.

Comment: There is this bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=20081 but it was way back in 2014. Do you have the latest Xamarin.Forms. Because this works in my solution. And please check if you have the same linking properties in Android and iOS both.

Comment: I solved that problem, 
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonResult);

string token = "";

foreach (var obj in dynJson)
{
    if(obj.Name.Equals("api_token")) 
    {
 token = obj.Value.ToString();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

```
public async Task Login(string inlogData, string password, string gcm) 
    {
        Login login = new Dharma.Login ();
        login.inlog_data = inlogData;
        login.password = password;
        login.phone_token = gcm;

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login, Formatting.Indented);
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds (10000);
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri (ConstantVariabels.GetLoginUrl());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var content = new StringContent (json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        try 
        {
            response = await client.PostAsync (client.BaseAddress, content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode ();
            var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result;

            dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonResult);

            string token = "";

            foreach (var obj in dynJson)
            {
                if(obj.Name.Equals("api_token")) 
                {
                     token = obj.Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            LoginPageViewModel.LoginSucceeded(token, true);
        }
        catch(TaskCanceledException te) 
        {
            LoginPageViewModel.LoginSucceeded(te.Message.ToString(), false);
        }
        catch(HttpRequestException hre) 
        {
            LoginPageViewModel.LoginSucceeded(hre.Message.ToString(), false);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            LoginPageViewModel.LoginSucceeded("fail", false);
        }
    }
```