# System.NotImplementedException: Interpreter of ref types

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm getting an exception while calling a web service in `xamarin.iOS`.

The exception is:

> System.NotImplementedException: Interpreter of ref types.

The same code working fine in Xamarin Android.

My code is as follows.

```
string postData = String.Format("grant_type=password&username={0}&password={1}", userName, password);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
string url = UrlConfig.LOGIN;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(url);
var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers[UrlConfig.DATAPOWER_KEY] = UrlConfig.DATAPOWER_VALUE;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
dataStream.Close();


using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
```

}

Comment: You should add the stack trace.

Comment: HTTP protocol errors cause a WebException btw

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37546543/json-deserializeobject-throws-exception-only-by-ios

Comment: ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/limitations/

Comment: i have added the stack trace, no result. Where I'm missing the flow?